# Class members encapsulation in Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, encapsulation

I started to wonder about class members encapsulation in Angular 9. I tried the Angular's documentation and googling it but haven't found any answer so far.
So, if I make them `private` they are visible only to their class members, obviously, and not to their html template.
If I make them `public` they are visible to any class and to the html as well.

So the question is:
**Is there a way to limit access of the variables/methods only to their class template file, aside of their class?** Is there some sort of golden mean?

Comment: nope. If you want to use it in your component's HTML, you have to use `public`

Answer (score 0):

private in typescript is just for your reference and it wont encapsulate the methods are variables.
All methods are public in typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with **protected**. Yes it is not only in template file but lesser visible as public.